# Puppet auto add new nodes

Tags: puppet

Ran in to some problems with puppet when doing an automatic expansion of our virtual cluster. As the puppetmaster only have the existing nodes in /etc/hosts and the new nodes we create are not in the DNS we get this error in the puppet master log when the new node tries to connect to master:

```
node-4 has a waiting certificate request
Signed certificate request for node-4
Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest node-4 at /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/node-4.pem'
Error: Could not resolve 192.168.0.37: no name for 192.168.0.37
```

Is there anyway to get around this? (Except adding in DNS/etc/hosts)

Comment: Not sure why this problem even crops up. FWIW, this has been asked and answered on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/654631/puppet-master-attempts-to-resolve-agent-hostname) already.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it is actually a false error, the root cause was that the site.pp file had a misspelled module name in the expanded node type.